# IE9 Placeholder.js Bug

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9, placeholder

Im using placeholder.js for my HTML5 attribute 'placeholder' on IE9.

My issue is when the page initially loads, the input field is still showing no placeholder. Once I click and focus inside of the input field and focus back out it works. Im having problems understanding what could causing this.

Im loading placeholder.js here in the footer

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<!--Third Party Dependencies-->
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/libs/harvey.js"></script>
<script src="/js/libs/screen.js"></script>
<script src="/js/libs/placeholder.min.js"></script>
<!--Application Scripts-->
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controllers/couponCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="/js/services/mobileDetection.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

Here is the input field:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control email-address-input" name="userEmail" ng-model="email.text" placeholder="ENTER EMAIL ADDRESS" ng-class="{ 'error': emailForm.userEmail.$error.email }" required>
```

Any feedback would be great, if you have any questions feel free to ask. 
Thanks, Jay.

Comment: Have you tried to use IE's dev tools to force hover and focus states to see what's going on? Perhaps you have colliding CSS?

Comment: maybe your input has initial forcus. try blur on load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that for Internet Explorer 9, the angular model `ng-model="email.text"` is being inserted into the input field.

```
$scope.toggleEmailClick = function(){
    $scope.coupon.showEmailForm = !$scope.coupon.showEmailForm;
    $scope.coupon.emailSent = false;
    $scope.email.text = "";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    Placeholders.enable();
}, 100);
```

Comment: Code without explanation isn't clear for users. Please explain.